# Android : Convert Base64Binary to Image

Tags: android, image, web-services, base64

In my application, I am using a web-service which returns an image in base64Binary format.
I am using ksoap2 to interact with the web-services.

Can anyone provide me any help regarding how to receive the base64Binary and then convert it into an image  ?

This is the code I use interact with the web-service.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_GET_CONTROL);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
    new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

 try {
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GET_CONTROL, envelope);
        ..........=envelope.getResponse(); //To get the data. }
```

How do I receive the data in base64Binary format  and then convert it into a png image ?

Comment: Please Check out the [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888746/android-get-image-from-base64binary-format

I think it help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MdAbdulGafur, the following answer worked for me :

```
decodedIcon[] = null;
byte[] bb = (resposeString).getBytes("utf-8");
decodedIcon = Base64.decodeBase64(bb);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedIcon, 0, decodedIcon.length);

mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Source : [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888746/android-get-image-from-base64binary-format).